# Jquery Mobile how to change the value of a button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Currently I have a button in which there is no value and I would like to change it when some ajax is called. However my attempts have failed can anyone help as to how I can change and retrieve the value from the button. Below is my code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       $('#favourite').val("4");
   });
</script>

<a href="#" id="favourite" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right"  value="">mark as favourite</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('#favourite').attr('value','4');
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFXfZ/).

**EDIT**

As it was pointed out in the comments by Tolis Emmanouilidis below the 'value' attribute for the anchor tag is invalid. So I would suggest using another `data-` attribute instead.

Example.

`<a id="favourite" data-value="">CLICK ME</a>`

and then to set the value with jQuery.

```
$('#favourite').on('click',function(){
   $(this).data('value','4');
});
```

and likewise to return the value.

`$(this).data('value');`

Comment: The value attribute is invalid for the HTML anchor tag.

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis ooo I didn't know that, thanks. However this still seems to work.

Comment: @KernElliott can you use another `data-` attribute?

Comment: @vletech it doesn't matter what i use once I can store and get the value. I cannot use text though

Comment: @vletech You're welcome :) It works because in that case the jQuery attr method gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements. In my opinion the fact that the value attribute is invalid for the anchor tag, explains why the jQuery val method does not work in that case.

Comment: @KernElliott You could use a JS variable to store the value.

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis then I will have to implement an onclick function for the button which will be `$(#favourite).click(){ //some code}` correct?